# Android multiple text view multi line issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Suppose there are four `TextViews` and there is a menu icon at the right most:

```
one two three four   menu icon
```

In the fourth text the text will be something like this:

```
Krishanu Das(one)  shared(two) avoy roy(three) 's post(four)
```

That means the text is

```
Krishanu Das shared avoy roy 's post
```

Sometimes it will be

```
Krishanu Das(one) 's post(two)
```

Then the two other `TextViews` will be Gone/Invisible.

My problem is that whenever the size of two `TextViews` [one & three] is increased, it touches the menu icon which is placed at the most right side.

I am using `wrap_content` for those four `TextViews`.
I want that whenever the user's name length is increased, the `TextViews` automatically spill to multiline.

Here is how my layout looks now:

[image: current layout]

Here is my design code of header:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="postheader1"

        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:textColor="#103c60" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_header_2ndpart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="'s Post"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/post_header"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post_headerdown_view"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/shedHeader_rltv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/post_header_2ndpart"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post_headerdown_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oneUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:text="postheader2"

            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:textColor="#103c60" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"

            android:text="'s Post"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oneUserName"

            android:textColor="#000" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post_headerdown_view"
        android:textColor="#103c60" />
```

Comment: Share your screen also. And also this seems to be not your full `XML` code. so Post full `XML` code also.

Comment: @Subho try setting weight to button in LinearLayout. I didn't got your question completely. Sorry if got wrong

Comment: Here is the screen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_TUaWwnPSeHQWF5M2hHcGRPZDA/view?usp=sharing
Check the link

Comment: @Subho Please update your full `XML` code also.

Comment: @jaydroider Do you understand what is my issue???

Comment: Here is my full code of single layout of a list view.
http://hastebin.com/robawinude.xml

Comment: @Subho 
 
I have checked your code please elaborate something more with problem. as i can be able to see what screen shot you have given with code. Which TextViews you need to be fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine all textview in one `RelativeLayout` and make them left aligned to `Menu` button. XML code is :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/post_menu" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="postheader1"

    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:textColor="#103c60" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_header_2ndpart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="'s Post"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/post_header"
    android:layout_below="@+id/post_headerdown_view"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/shedHeader_rltv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/post_header_2ndpart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/post_headerdown_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oneUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="postheader2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#103c60" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text="'s Post"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oneUserName"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post_headerdown_view"
        android:textColor="#103c60" />
```